# When should override and use custom primary key django?

Tags: database, django-models, orm, primary-key, django-orm

Inheriting django **Model** causes a model to have a default primary key (id),

by default django generates **BigAutoField** for primary keys.

I have Checked some of the famous apps written in django like *posthog*, *zulip*, *sentry*, *mozilla addons-server* and all of them have used custom primary key.

(some of them have used both custom primary key and default)

I'm wondering when should we override this behavior and have custom primary key?

to clarify: obviously, my question is not when should change the primary key to something else (e.g. to name or email field), cause that depends on your desicion
actually.

I wanna know what is drawback of the default primary key and should I be worried about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One drawback is that the default autofield increments by 1 each time, so your first model instance will have an id of 1 then 2 then 3 etc. Let's say that you can access user public profiles by `domain.com/<userid>/profile`. This is a security risk because it's trivial to find out the database ID of any given user, the number of users etc, and this holds true for any model that uses that pattern.

Comment: thank your for your answer.
but in our app there is a strict permission system, and we have a company model 
which all other models are related to the company models including users,
so anyone who has access (company admin gave him the accesses) co do what you've explained, and another user will be blocked calling domain.com/<userid>/profile.

more explanation and reasons would be appreciated.

Comment: The example I gave isn't really a showstopper type issue, as there are plenty of ways around it - using another primary key, using a slug in the url instead, etc. It is something to bear in mind about your approach, though. If bigautofield was an all-round terrible option they wouldn't have it as default.